# recognize highlighted Image in UI Automation

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

UIImageView has a property called highlighted on images. Can UI automation recognize this property? is there a way for me to find out the highlighted images using IOS UIAutomation API?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you -

UIImageView Class Reference -

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_8
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, UIAutomation has no UIImage class, that's where my problem is